# jQuery read all TD's table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With jquery I am reading table:

```
$('#lc_searchresult > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var data = $(this).find("td:eq(5)").html();
            alert(data);        
        });
```

it is working fine if `TR` tag has one `TD` inside like:

```
<tr>
<td>654321</td>       
</tr>
```

but If I am having two `TD's` then I am geting just first one:

```
<tr>
<td>654321</td>            
<td>13456</td>        
</tr>
```

How can I get all of `TD's` from `TR` with `$(this).find("td:eq(5)").html()`

Comment: Looks like you can iterate `tr`s, what's the problem when you need to iterate `td`s?

Comment: I do not know what is the best. Create new .each(function() inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#lc_searchresult > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  $(this).children('td').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).html();
  alert(data);
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `eq` it? You're using `.each()` which means you will return an array of `<tr>`'s.

```js
$('#lc_searchresult > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).find('td').text();
    alert(data);        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lc_searchresult">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>654321</td>            
                <td>13456</td>        
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>4353535</td>            
                <td>3453553</td>        
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bua8xyoe/2)

Answer (score 0):

this should work,

**note thier is no need to use :eq selector here,

[READ ABOUT JQUERY :eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```js
$('#lc_searchresult > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  var data = $(this).html();
  alert(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='lc_searchresult'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>654321</td>
      <td>13456</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

td:eq(5) : mean you get data of TD with exactly index. so you can't get all data of TR with eq().

Answer (score 0):

well when you write

```
var data = $(this).find("td");
```

the variable data contains an array of all the td's not just the first one

if you say

```
data.each(function(){
    alert($(this).html())
})
```

you will get all the td's